# How to escape correctly this word on vim?

Tags: vim, regular-expression, escape-characters

I want to substitute this word
`${ARRAY1[@]}` with `$1` on vim substitution command
I did

```
:%s:\$\{ARRAY1[\@]\}:\$1:g
```

But give me error about number of repetition,i try also "" but doesn't work
How to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%s/\${ARRAY1\[@\]}/$1/
```

worked for me. Apparently, you must escape [ and ] but not { and }.
I always use / instead of : as seperation, but

```
%s:\${ARRAY1\[@\]}:$1:g
```

works as well.

Comment: To figure out what should or should not be escaped, read the vim documentation on the `magic` option: `:help 'magic'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
:%s:\${ARRAY1\[@\]}:$1:g
```